# jQuery - crossfade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in javascript:

```
 function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              $(".body_image").fadeOut(300);
              $(".body_image").fadeIn(300);
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              $(".body_image").fadeOut(100);
              $(".body_image").fadeIn(200);
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = 0;
          images[0] = "images/image1.png";   
          images[1] = "images/image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "images/image3.jpg";
          images[3] = "images/image4.jpg";
          images[4] = "images/image4.jpg";
          images[5] = "images/image4.jpg";
```

And effect between two images is bad. I want crossfade effect how can I do it? 
Thx for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your needs, you want to:

1. `fadeOut()` the current image
2. Replace the image
3. Fade back in

`fadeOut()` takes an optional completion function; use that to replace the image and start the fade-in.

```js
 function displayNextImage() {
   x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;

   $(".body_image").fadeOut(300,
     function() {
       document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
       $(".body_image").fadeIn(300);
     });
 }

 function displayPreviousImage() {
   x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;

   $(".body_image").fadeOut(300,
     function() {
       document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
       $(".body_image").fadeIn(300);
     });
 }

 function startTimer() {
   setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
 }

 var x = 0,
   images = [
     "//placehold.it/200/ff0000/000000",
     "//placehold.it/200/00ff00/000000",
     "//placehold.it/200/0000ff/000000",
     "//placehold.it/200/ffff00/000000",
     "//placehold.it/200/ffffff/000000",
     "//placehold.it/200/ff00ff/000000"
   ];

 startTimer()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body_image">
  <img id=img src="//placehold.it/200/ff0000/000000" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code fades the new image in while fading the previous image out.  Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fc7b1ktw/1/

And the code:

```
function displayNextImage() {
  crossFade(x,x+1);
}

function displayPreviousImage() {
  crossFade( x,x-1);
}

function crossFade( imageOut, imageIn ) {
  var i = $( ".image-" + imageIn % 2 ),
    timing = 500;
  x = imageIn % images.length;
  i.attr( 'src', images[ x ] );
  $( ".image-" + imageOut % 2 ).fadeOut(timing);
  i.fadeIn(timing);
}

function startTimer() {
  displayNextImage();
  setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
}

var images = [
     "http://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg",
     "http://cdn.phys.org/newman/gfx/news/hires/2013/takingtheran.jpg",
     "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30800000/-Random-random-30843841-1920-1080.jpg",
     "http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/models/Sample%20Models/Mathematics/Probability/Random%20Walk%20360.png"
  ],
  x = 0;

startTimer();
```